# Is the complex cobordism spectrum, $MU$, a finite spectrum?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cobordism, stable-homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Is the complex cobordism spectrum, $MU$, a finite spectrum?

If yes, what other examples of finite spectrums there are? Is the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum finite?

What about the connective $K$-theory $ku$?

Answer (score 2):

No, none of these are finite spectra.  An easy way to tell is by taking homology: any finite spectrum has nontrivial homology in only finitely many degrees, but $MU$, $H\mathbb{Z}$, and $ku$ all have nontrivial homology in infinitely many degrees.

Typically, finite spectra arise not as particularly natural cohomology theories, but as suspension spectra of spaces.  Indeed, a spectrum is finite iff it is a shift of the suspension spectrum of a finite CW-complex.

Comment: What about $BP$, the Brown Peterson spectrum?

Comment: Also not finite, for the same reason.